# Questions about less popular games

Tags: discussion, questions

If I'd like to ask something about a game that is less (or absolutely not) popular, can it be too localized?

I mean, these questions can be of the type that only provides a solution for me, if I'm the only one who is strongly interested in that game.

I can expect that I won't get answer, but that's not a big problem for me.

Comment: Too localized no longer exists, and this definitely is **not** how it would have been applied when it did exist.  Please ask your question(s).

Comment: @JasonBerkan Oh yes, I've heard about the recreating of bad question categories on Stack Exchange. I didn't know that it also involved "too localized" type.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt The "too localized" type hasn't been "recreated" or anything. It was a vote that was more often misused than appropriately used, so it was eliminated for not doing its job. We have other ways of preventing *real* too localised questions from staying on the site. Regardless, no game that has been published is ever too localised, either now or before.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd argue that we *don't* have other ways for killing real TL questions (aside from misusing *other* close reasons), but that's a different topic, I believe.

Comment: TIL that I'm not the only one that asks questions about less-known (or older) games.

Comment: I was just going to post another question more or less similar to this one but found this one on the suggested questions list.

Since my first day on Arqade I wanted to ask questions on some mini (not so much popular) Android games but always stopped myself. I searched for some of them and couldn't find any questions and therefore thought that they were out of Arqade's scope. Recently I've created a new tag for Sky Force 2014 but this title is already very popular. Would it be OK to ask on less popular titles which maybe are limited only to the Android platform?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as it's a game that anybody can play, feel free to ask about it.  I'm frequently in the spot of playing games that one or maybe two other people here play.  I would still ask questions about it if I was stuck.

We can't guarantee you'll get an answer in a timely manner, but we can guarantee that we allow questions about obscure and less popular games.

Comment: I don't mind if I don't get an answer. I like asking with the philosophy of "no one have asked it, but may be useful for anyone".

Comment: Don't expect much voting on it, unless you manage to come up with a really witty title.  But if you got stuck somewhere, or you think someone else will get stuck at a specific point, there's no reason not to ask about it.

Comment: My question is not related to the gameplay but thanks!

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt If it's not about the gameplay, it may have to meet other criteria for it to be acceptable here.  About playing the game, on-topic.  About something related to the game, maybe.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt In the case of an unpopular game that you ask a question about, please do not hesitate to answer it yourself when you do find the answer.